# Compiling with MPIcc and including MPI.h I receive the following "error: use of undeclared identifier 'MPI_COMM_WORLD'"

Tags: compilation, mpi

I have a C code I'm trying to implement in parallel using MPI. I'm using standard expressions such as:

```
/* initialize mpi */
MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );
```

I however receive this error:

```
"error: use of undeclared identifier 'MPI_COMM_WORLD'
 MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );"
```

I have:

```
 #include <mpi.h>
```

at the top of the file..

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: The predefined communicator `MPI_COMM_WORLD` must be provided by MPI... One way to get such an error would be to place the ` #include <mpi.h> ` in a conditional directive. For instance, `#undef FOURTYTWO #ifdef FOURTYTWO #include <mpi.h> #endif`

Comment: So it complains about the line with `MPI_Comm_size(...)` but not about the previous one?

Comment: In response: There is no conditional statement around the include file and yes it does throw the same error for the other usage of MPI_COMM_WORLD.

Comment: Maybe there are other messages that might hint what is going wrong---wrap the above snippet in main() {} and show the complete compiler output.

Comment: It will help if you share with us what MPI implementation you are using, what OS, and what compiler. The output of `mpicc --show` might also prove useful.